# Work around python's json module not liking circular references

Tags: python, json

Other than using an external library (like maybe [jsonpickle](https://jsonpickle.github.io/), though I haven't tried it), is there a way to get python's `json` module to `dump` a dictionary  (or list, etc) that has circular references (just dropping the reference, that is)?

I only want to use json to more easily see some debug output.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid another library. You could use YAML, I'm pretty sure that can handle circular references.

Comment: In my case, I'm running inside google app engine and it's easier to just not include an external lib (unless it provides lots of value). But I'm sure others have different reasons. Links to other libs are certainly helpful, though, just not the main question.

Answer (score 3):

Well, avoiding anything but standard modules, here's one solution which utilizes `repr` for handling the circular references. EDIT: For the latest, see [all-purpose function for dumping any python thing in a mostly-readable manner (aka dump)](https://gist.github.com/patkujawa-wf/ae978919f4c68c9c8de8)

```
# MAGIC-NUMBER: max length is just some guess at a reasonable size, e.g. 80 cols by 100 lines
def dump(value, msg='DUMP', max_length=80 * 100, stdout=False, pick=None):
    """
    Write as verbose of a description of the value as possible to logging.DEBUG.

    See http://stackoverflow.com/q/27830888/116891

    :param value: The item of interest.
    :type value: object
    :param msg: Prefix for the logged item (default='DUMP')
    :type msg: basestring
    :param max_length: Longest allowed string length (set to None for unlimited)
    :type max_length: int
    :param stdout: If true, print instead of logging (default=False)
    :type stdout: bool
    :param pick: If specified, dump only values for these keys of the item
        (value must be a dict or allow __dict__ access).
        The name comes from http://underscorejs.org/#pick.
    :type pick: iterable of basestring
    :return: True if message dumped
    :rtype: bool
    """
    if not logging.getLogger().isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG) and not stdout:
        return

    if pick:
        d = value if isinstance(value, dict) else value.__dict__
        filtered = {
            property_name: d[property_name]
            for property_name in pick
            if property_name in d
        }
        value = filtered

    kwargs = dict(indent=2, sort_keys=True)
    try:
        import json
        info = json.dumps(value, **kwargs)
    except:
        # JSON doesn't like circular references :/
        try:
            string_repr = repr(value)
            # Replace python primitives, single-quotes, unicode, etc
            string_repr = string_repr\
                .replace('None', 'null')\
                .replace('True', 'true')\
                .replace('False', 'false')\
                .replace("u'", "'")\
                .replace("'", '"')

            # Replace object and function repr's like <MyObject ...>
            string_repr = re.sub(r':(\s+)(<[^>]+>)', r':\1"\2"', string_repr)

            # Replace tuples with lists, very naively
            string_repr = string_repr.replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']')

            info = json.dumps(json.loads(string_repr), **kwargs)
        except:
            from pprint import pformat
            info = pformat(value, indent=2)

    def _out(formatted_string, *format_args):
        """Format the string and output it to the correct location."""
        if stdout:
            print(formatted_string % format_args)
        else:
            logging.debug(formatted_string, *format_args)

    if max_length is None or len(info) <= max_length:
        _out('%s: %s', msg, info)
        return True
    else:
        _out(
            'Did not dump "%s" due to length restriction. Increase max_length if desired.', msg
        )
    return False
```

Comment: Don't just do `except:` that will catch system exceptions.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm being lazy. Although, if there is a system exception, it will most likely be re-raised during the final except clause. This isn't for production logging ;)

Comment: Hah! So I get a vote down with no comment. Sometimes I think people take coding answers too personally!